# Are there complexity classes so that RE ⊂ C ⊂ ALL?

Tags: computability

If so what are they? These are Computational Complexity Classes that are not in RE but are in ALL. What would a problem in one of these classes look like? Would any of these problems be decidable?

Comment: For example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy .

Comment: Any class that contains RE has undecidable problems.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus. Yes i know that. But what I'm asking is are there any decidable problems that are not in RE?

Comment: RE contains all decidable problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been commented above, decidability **implies** recursive enumerability - indeed, one of the standard exercises in any computability theory book is proving that a set is decidable iff it is both r.e. and co-r.e. (note that "decidable," "recursive," and "computable" are all synonyms). So no, a fortiori there are no decidable problems outside of $\mathsf{RE}$.

But that doesn't mean that there aren't interesting non-r.e. problems or classes of problems. For example, the set $\mathsf{Tot}$ of (indices for) Turing machines which halt on *all* inputs is strictly more complicated than any r.e. set; in a precise sense it is [the halting problem's halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump).

A good starting point here is the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy). This may seem abstract at first, but results like [Post's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem) and [Shoenfield's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_in_the_limit#Limit_lemma) will help demystify it. And even that is only the start of the very intricate picture; further keywords include "**hyper**arithmetic" and "projective."

I strongly recommend the treatment in the first part of Soare's original recursion theory textbook.